Visual Studio crashes whenever I use git
I've been using Visual Studio to work on my C++ coding. When I try to create a git repo the application crashes.
This issue is reproducible for me through the simple steps

Create an empty project, call it Project, which now exists at C:\Users\name\source\repos\Project.
Go to Create Git Repository, add a name, and hit create repository.

I noticed that the local repo path is default C:\Users\name, and it doesn't allow me to change this path. Looking at examples online the local repo path is always C:\Users\name\source\repos\Project. This could be involved with the issue.
Edit: The "crash" consists of Visual Studio freezing and eventually going unresponsive, during which time my PC is incredibly slow. Eventually the application goes unresponsive and I get the option to wait/restart/close. Also note that the repo does get created as I can see it on github.

Hi, Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A. I don't think what you have there is a programming question. It's more of a Visual Studio bug report. Which you should report through the appropriate channels. If I overlooked your question, please [edit] your post to make it more obvious. Also [ask] may have some helpful tips.

One obvious question you will probably be asked is "how do I reproduce your problem from a clean install?". And anything special about your system and/or configuration.

I believe your assumption is correct that the repo location is the problem. What is the number of files and total size of the folder (and all sub-folders) C:\Users\name? That is likely not a good place to put a Git repository, and I believe VS is probably creating the repo there and then running git status which could take a while for huge folders.
